# How can I set my horizontal line to stay behind my divs?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I'm not sure what is going on behind the scene here. I couldn't set my blue line to the back of my divs.

I've try adjusting the z-index to `0` , the line is stay on top of my divs.

Then, I decrease one by adjusting the z-index to:
`-1` , the line disappear completely. ???

I'm clueless now.

**CSS**

My line class = `.tl-line`:

```
.tl-line:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        border-bottom: 1px #3498db dashed;
        z-index: 0;
        top: 27%;
        margin-top:-2px;
        right: 7%;
        left: 7%;
        width: 88%; 
    }
```

Here is my live result : [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/e9L60rfr/9/)

Comment: Please show a picture or something of how you want your line to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following:

```
.tl-box, .tl-right, .mp-arrow-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;       
  background: white;
}
```

This will place the boxes on top of the dotted line.  The background is needed to prevent the line from bleeding through.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsug7w8s/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.tl-box {
    position:relative;    /* add this */
    z-index:1;            /* add this */
```

Do the same for any other element you want to overlap the dashed line.

Though you'll have problems placing you dashed line above the left arrow, cause your HTML and CSS are basically misplaced and overly complicated. The JS slider stuff can also be simplified, but that's another story.
My suggestion is to place the left arrow HTML right after the element that has the dashed line pseudo, but than you need to fix their CSS positions too.

Comment: Just curious. How did you identify this specific class as being the problem area? Works great.

Comment: @LynelHudson well, first I've used `inspect element` option, I've seen what he did with the `:before` element and since it's absolute positioned, I realized we need to handle the other elements that need to overlap adding position, or fixing completely your HTML and CSS but that would take lot of time...

Comment: @LynelHudson well, seems like the accepted one was particularily different from my answer.... :P Mine was more like a guidance, but Ritch added all the needed classes. I'm still after remaking the whole concept, cause in my experience, as soon you start to use `z-index` means something is misplaced in HTML (at least 90% of the time :) )

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to step on your toes.  I posted before I saw your answer, but I left mine up since the background seemed to be needed.

Comment: @RickHitchcock great addon! No worries :) I'm just here to help, not to compete!